# Loop through li elements with next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have content in ul li as below:

```
<ul>
  <li>Content 1 Detail</li> 
  <li>Content 2 Detail</li> 
  <li>Content 2 Detail</li> 
</ul>
```

Now i want to show `content 2` on click on next button and so on. I tried [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYnYM/20/) but back link in it does not work.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, both on the next and previous function, it shouldnt be `.appendTo('ul')` Because it will duplicated the `li` (check the DOM). Use instead `.appendTo($(this).parent()`.

Also, the reason why it is not working is because you use inside the `fadeOut()` callback `$(this).parent('.container')`. But inside that callback, `this === li` and it has no parent `.container`.

You can however only use `.parent()` without arguments and it work : http://jsfiddle.net/zYnYM/27/

Comment: cheers :)  .. u saved life